# ImageView Мутное изображение

Tags: java, android, imageview

В приложении есть ViewFlipper в котором есть ImageView с картинками @minmap

Первая проблема в том, что она мутно выводится, сама картинка с большим 
разрешением. Вторая, у нее по всем четырем сторонам отступы.

Пробывал установить картинку как background, и как srcCompat, и даже менял ImageView на LinearLayout, не помогает решить не одну из проблем.

Пожалуйста, помогите советом. В андроид разработке новичек.

Comment: Можно код разметки?

Comment: Попробуйте перенеси картинку в `drawable` папку - `mipmap` только для иконки самого приложения используется.